# In/on/at a Facebook/Reddit/Stackexchange post/tweet

Tags: prepositions

I'm pretty sure it should be "*in* a tweet" (perhaps because a tweet is short?). And perhaps also the same for a Facebook post?

But for a long Reddit/Stack Exchange post (perhaps with many replies and answers), should/could we use *in*/*on*/*at*?

Examples:

1. As was mentioned ___ this Stack Exchange post (*with a question, many answers, and many comments*), ...
2. As stated in the selected answer ___ this Stack Exchange post (*ditto*), ...
3. See the discussion ___ this Stack Exchange answer.
4. See the discussion ___ this Stack Exchange post (*ditto*).
5. See the many discussions ___ English Stack Exchange.
6. See the many discussions ___ r/English.
7. See the discussion ___ english.stackexchange.com/questions/123456789 (*ditto*).

(What are the deeper explanations for why we might choose one preposition over another here?)

Comment: Can you give an example sentence? The correct preposition may vary.

Comment: You'd use "he wrote in a letter" or "he wrote in a novel" for a part of a letter or novel, so I'm not sure length is an issue, but it's possible you mean the entire tweet, as in "He replied in/with a tweet". Also by "Reddit/Stackexchange post" are you referring just to the original question/post by the OP, or the question plus replies (normally called a thread on messageboards)?

Comment: It is fairly uncontroversial that one says something in a post, while the post itself is on this or that site. Without an elaboration of the question, it is difficult to know what the problem is that the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: If you don't know this , you should probably be posting in [ell.se].

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["publish in" vs. "publish on"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94584/publish-in-vs-publish-on)